# How to prepend a single line to a csv file in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory

I have a csv/txt file in Azure Blob Storage of the form:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data |

In the text file it looks like:

Column1, Column2, Column3, etc.

data, data, data, etc.

I am attempting to prepend a single line in ADF as the first line in the file so that it looks like:

BATCH IMPORT, IMPORT 1.0 (the comma is included in this line)

Column1, Column2, Column3, etc.

data, data, data, etc.

I have attempted to use merge files, changed the delimiting around but can't seem to make it work. There is no need to work with the data after this line has been prepended. I will be using a binary copy activity to send it to its destination once the line has been added. Is there any way to achieve this in ADF without using external sources like Azure Functions or Batch Services?

Thanks for helping in advance.

Edit: I would also be happy to work with Azure Functions for this as well if that is possible?

Comment: `BATCH IMPORT, IMPORT 1.0`,  Is this header definite? Isn't it dynamically generated?

Comment: Header is fixed, not dynamic. Thanks for the answer!! will give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/data-flow-create) in ADF to achieve that.

1. We can add a csv or text file contains the header `BATCH IMPORT, IMPORT 1.0` to  Azure Blob Storage.
   [image]
2. Then at `source1` we connect to the source csv.
   [image]
3. Select `No delimiter` at source dataset.
   [image]
   Data preview is as follows:
   [image]
4. Add another source of headers.txt, which contains the single line `BATCH IMPORT, IMPORT 1.0` .
   [image]
5. The same, select `No delimiter` at the dataset.
   [image]
   Data preview is as follows:
   [image]
6. Union `header` and `source1`  at `Union1` activity
   [image]
   Data preview is as follows:
   [image]
7. Then we can sink to a csv
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

We had the same requirement recently (well, we wanted to append rows to a csv in blob).

Waiting 5 mins to spin up a Spark cluster to do this seemed like overkill so our workaround was to read it into a table in SQL, append the data in a proc there and write back to blob.

Maybe not elegant but it does the job!

Comment: ELT patterns, use the compute available to you, rather than spin up new compute (and wait), I’m all for it.  +10 from me.