# Append rows to azure data lake gen 1 file

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have loaded data from Oracle to Azure data lake gen 1 in `.txt` format using `copy activity`. This is a Full load.

Now, I want to do incremental/delta load. How can I add new rows to same sink file?

**Issue:**
The data get replaced when I give the same name which is present in SINK side.

**Expected:**
Instead I want to append this new rows to the file.

Can some one please suggest/guide the process to achieve this?

Comment: This might answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66484987/how-to-prepend-a-single-line-to-a-csv-file-in-azure-data-factory/66615619#66615619

Comment: Hi @Python coder, is the error solved now?

Comment: @LeonYue No. I was not able to find the answer yet.